# How to read data from a file and put it into variable and output to a different file. Java

Tags: java

Intro java class tard here. I'm trying to read data from a file and then manipulate to a different file and save it. I think i'm close but having issues using scanner and .IO together.  Any help would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class fileswitch
{

    public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException
    {
        String filename;
        String filename2;
        String text;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the name of a file: ");
        filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

        System.out.print("Enter the name of a second file: ");
        filename2 = keyboard.nextLine();

        PrintWriter outputFile2 = new PrintWriter(filename2);

        while (filename.hasNextLine())
        {
            text = filename.readAllLines();
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            outputFile2.print(text);
            outputFile2.close();
        }       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use for creating a new file

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class WriteStringToFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String string = "This is\na test";
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, string);
    }
}
```

And that is a good practice because you do not have to close streams.

This generates the test.txt file with the expected output

Comment: +1 Great example of using an existing solution to a common problem instead of inventing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BufferedReader`

```
BufferedReader pw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); 
String s = null;
s = pw.readLine();
```

---

Working example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filePath = keyboard.next();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Enter path on console as

```
C:\Users\path\Desktop\1.txt
```

---

You can use `PrintWriter` to write

```
PrintWriter out   = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile.

```
while (filename.hasNextLine()) // String#hasNextLine() does not exist
```

`hasNextLine()` belongs to `Scanner` which isn't being used for reading the file but just your console keystrokes from the keyboard.

If you meant to use `outputFile` there; that won't work either because you can't use a `PrintWriter` as a file reader. Well, the name kind of makes that obvious. Doesn't it?

But, you should avoid using `PrintWriter` for writing as well unless you're formatting the output. For plain character output prefer a `FileWriter` (enclosed within a `BufferedWriter` for performance). Similarly, for reading the files prefer a `FileReader` (enclosed within a `BufferedReader` again).

Here's how your code would look:

```
public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException
{
    // create the scanner for console 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // read the input/output file names
    System.out.print("Enter the name of a file: ");
    String inFile = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the name of a second file: ");
    String outFile = keyboard.nextLine();

    // close the scanner
    keyboard.close();

    // open file streams
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));

    // copy the data (line by line)
    String text = null;
    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        writer.write(text);
        writer.newLine();
    }

    // close the file streams
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
}
```